# Django Custom User admin page

Tags: python, django

I am currently trying to implement my admin page for the custom user model I have made. I have added a field called 'email_confirmed', and I am trying to get this to display on the Admin page.

This is the model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    """User model."""
    abstract = True
    username = None
    email = EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    email_confirmed = BooleanField(default = False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'second_name']

    objects = UserManager()

    def get_full_name(self):
        fname = self.first_name
        lname = self.last_name
        return '{} {}'.format(fname, lname)

    def email_confirmed(self):
        return self.email_confirmed
```

As you can see I have tried writing a method called email confirmed to get this to work, however it didn't work.

This is the UserAdmin I have in my admin.py:

```
@admin.register(get_user_model())
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    class Meta:

        model = get_user_model()

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email_confirmed')}),
        (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                                       'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2', 'email_confirmed()'),
        }),
    )
    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff', 'email_confirmed')
    search_fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email_confirmed')
    ordering = ('email',)
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: what exactly do you want to display on your admin page?

Comment: I want to have all the default stuff showing, with the addition of 'email_confirmed'

Comment: are you overriding the `__str__()` function in the class? cuz it's the one that's called when you print the object or when the admin page renders it.

Comment: No I haven't in the model I posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't write this method

```
def email_confirmed(self):
    return self.email_confirmed
```

Comment: Sorted it! Thank you!